# What is the simpliest way to make a list of coordinates?

Tags: yaml

I need to put a list of 2D-integer coordinates in a YAML configuration file.

Ideally, I would like to make a list with one set of coordinates on each line:

```
coords:
 - # X1 Y1
 - # X2 Y2
 - # X3 Y3
 - # etc
```

I thought about make strings that would be composed of two numbers and a separator that I could parse easily, like this:

```
coords:
 - 42,42
 - 21,84
 - 666,1337
```

But is there a way to make it properly in YAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cooridinates are essentially a sequence of two integers, you can get them on one line using flow style:

```
coords:
- [42, 42]
- [21, 84]
- [666, 1337]
```

Note that the dashes don't have to be indented to make the sequence be the value of the key `coords`. This will load as top-level mapping, with a sequence as value, and the items in those sequence being each sequences of two integers. That loads without you having to do any string to integer conversion.